# Number of valid sequences

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, dynamic-programming, largenumber

A sequence of *n* numbers is considered valid if the sequence begins with 1, ends with a given number *j*, and no two adjacent numbers are the same. Sequences may use any integers between 1 and a given number *k*, inclusive (also 1 <= *j* <= *k*). Given parameters *n, j, k,* count the number of valid sequences. The number of valid sequences may be very large, so express your answer modulo 10<sup>10</sup> + 7.

I'm trying to find a linear time solution to this problem. This is from a competition a friend did a few years back.

e.g.

1) n = 4, k = 4, j = 2.

2) n = 10<sup>7</sup>, k = 10<sup>12</sup>, j = 829.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Okay. I accept your definitions. What is your *question*?

Comment: Do you have the answers to any test cases so we can check our logic?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

I get 7 for the first example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will outline enough of it to get you going.  But will leave you most of the work.

Note that, thanks to symmetry, after any number of turns the number of ways of winding up at any particular non-1 value are the same as winding up at any other.  Therefore if `x_m_l` is the number of ways to construct a so-far-valid sequence that at `m` steps winds up at `l` then `x_m_2 == x_m_3 == ... == x_m_k`.  But `x_m_1` may be different.  So let's call `x_m_1` `x_m` and the others `y_m`.

We immediately have that `x_0 = 1` and `y_0 = 0`.  After a little thought we have `x_(m+1) = (k-1) * y_m`.  And `y_(m+1) = x_m + (k-2) * y_m`.

Writing that as a vector (excuse the bad ASCII art) the first one is:

```
( x_0 ) -- ( 1 )
( y_0 ) -- ( 0 )
```

And the second turns into the following matrix equation:

```
( x_(m+1) ) -- [ 0  k-1 ] ( x_m )
( y_(m+1) ) -- [ 1  k-2 ] ( y_m )
```

So far so good.  But let's call that transition matrix `T`.  It moves us forward one step.  But if you want to move forward 2 steps, you can just multiply by `T` twice.  `T^2`.  3 steps you just need `T^3`.  And so on.

The result is that `T^m` is the matrix to move forward `m` steps.  And `T^n` contains your answer.  (Whether you look at the first or second entries in the vector depends on whether `j=1` or something else.)

If you just calculate `T^n` by multiplying repeatedly (doing modulo arithmetic), you will get your desired answer.

If you're clever about repeated squaring you can actually solve it in logarithmic time.

For a related topic, see https://medium.com/@andrew.chamberlain/the-linear-algebra-view-of-the-fibonacci-sequence-4e81f78935a3